# Unable to import tensorflow - Failed to load native tensorflow runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have been using tensorflow for quite sometime now via Anaconda. Today, my computer crashed and I had to reinstall Anaconda again, post installation of tensorflow today, each time I try to import it, I get the following error -

```
(base) C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das>python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as t
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

When I do `pip freeze | findstr tensorflow`, I get the following details - `tensorflow==2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0`

I went through various answers here and in the github repo of tensorflow but in vain.

Any kind help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was waiting for a reply, I was able to solve the error on my own. 
The step-by-step guide is as follows:

1. Install **VS 2017**, tensorflow doesn't use it but having it helps in the smooth installation of CUDA toolkit.
2. Update **NVDIA driver from windows device manager**.
3. Download and Install **CUDA toolkit (version 10.1)**.
4. Download and unzip **CUDnn 7.6.5**. Copy the extracted files into a folder in C drive.
5. Add `~\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin`, `~\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin` and `cudnn-10.1-windows10-x64-v7.6.4.38\cuda\bin` to PATH

Doing `import tensorflow as tf` after the above steps solved the issue.